# I am trying to get data by using Oauth authentication in obj c ,but evertime I got the error of "oauth_problem=signature_invalid"

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing

```
-(void)getData:(void (^) (NSArray * result,NSError * error))completion{
    NSDictionary * jsonDic;
    __block NSString *responsebody = @"";
    OAConsumer *consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc] initWithKey:@"4ff70fabfa83728ca0febe33eaaa7c25"
                                                    secret:@"166980cbde6623913b66197458d658f2"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ordering.sonitekinternational.com/api/rest/customers/14/addresses"];
    OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                                                   consumer:consumer
                                                                      token:nil
                                                                      realm:nil
                                                          signatureProvider:nil];
    [request prepare];
    NSString *oauthHeader = @"OAuth ";
    oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@"oauth_consumer_key=\"%@\"",@"4ff70fabfa83728ca0febe33eaaa7c25"];
    oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@",oauth_token=\"%@\"",@"ac42663555d64e1707b109b100240842"];
    oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@",oauth_signature_method=\"%@\"",@"HMAC-SHA1"];
    oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@",oauth_signature=\"%@\"",[self encodeToPercentEscapeString:request.signature]];
    oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@",oauth_timestamp=\"%ld\"", (time_t) [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
    oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@",oauth_nonce=\"%@\"",request.nonce];
    oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@",oauth_version=\"1.0\""];
    oauthHeader = [oauthHeader stringByAppendingFormat:@",oauth_token_secret=\"%@\"",@"04b9f08ffd1fe00b5bda0241c2705ecb"];
       [request setValue:oauthHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    [request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    NSLog(@"Complete url is ==>>%@",request.URL);
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
                                      dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *_Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError *_Nullable error)
                                      {
                                          // Use the data here
                                          if(data == nil){
                                              completion(nil,error);
                                              return;
                                          }
                                          else{
                                              NSHTTPURLResponse *newResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
                                              NSLog(@"%ld", (long)newResp.statusCode);
                                              NSMutableArray *parsedObject;
                                              parsedObject=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
                                              NSLog(@"Parsed Data ===>>>%@",parsedObject);
                                            }
                                      }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

In this code I'm using

```
import "OAMutableURLRequest.h"

import "OAConsumer.h"
```

And when print the parsed data I got **

```
    Parsed Data ===>>>{
    messages =     {
        error =         (
                        {
                code = 401;
                message = "oauth_problem=signature_invalid";
            }
        );
    };
}
```

Anybody can help me? When I look at the http response code I get a 401. I've reached out to the service provider regarding the unexpected 401 response.

In the meanwhile, does anything stand out to you on what I'm possibly doing wrong?

Even just pointing me to some working sample code would be highly appreciated. I've read a lot of stuff out there, but I'm obviously getting some nuance wrong in obj-c.

Comment: Is this keys is valid?  OAConsumer *consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc] initWithKey:@"4ff70fabfa83728ca0febe33eaaa7c25"
                                                    secret:@"166980cbde6623913b66197458d658f2"];

Comment: yes I checked these keys are valid but I don't know exactly what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Recreate your OAConsumer keys.